# How to tell whether two class templates are the same

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, template-templates

Say I have a function that has two template template parameters like:

```cpp
template <template <typename...> C1, template <typename...> C2>
constexpr bool is_same_container() {
    return std::is_same<C1, C2>::value;
}

is_same_container<std::vector, std::vector>();
```

When I compile, the compiler complains that `C1` and `C2` needs to be supplied with template arguments.

**Is there any way to compare two class templates directly?**

`std::vector` should be the same thing as `std::vector`. How can I find out?

Comment: `std::vector` isn't a thing, while `std::vector<T>` is?

Comment: Wouldn't std::vector have to be parameterized with a type?

Comment: Templates have to be specialized in order to be real types. You can't compare `std::vector` to `std::vector`, but you can compare `std::vector<int>` to `std::vector<char>`, for instance.

Comment: `std::vector` is not a type, and it is not a container. It is a template for making types, and containers. However this is quite an interesting question and I'd be curious to see whether it can be done.

Comment: Yeah, I want to find out whether or not we can compare two *un-parametrized* templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just write your own trait.

```
template<template<class...> class C1, template<class...> class C2>
struct is_same_template : std::false_type {};

template<template<class...> class C>
struct is_same_template<C,C> : std::true_type {};
```

Answer (score -1):

this works for n variables, using variadic functions we can compare all the templates that we want

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
bool are_same(){
      bool value = std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Args>...>::value;
return value;
```

Comment: The question asks about something else. In any case, this should be a `concept` or `constexpr bool` variable or at least a `constexpr` function.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, why it should be a concept or constexpr bool variable?

Comment: Ultimately people will want to use it in a constexpr context (such as `if constexpr (...)`), so a non-constexpr function is no good. A constexpr function would work, but no standard traits are functions, they're either variables, concepts, or classes with `::value`, so you should be using one of those for consistency.

Comment: This has the same problem as the question: It confuses types and templates. `std::is_same<std::vector, std::vector>` doesn't work either. Also, in 2023 I'd just fold `std::is_same_v`