# Given a template argument, how to find out whether or not this is actually a parameterized template class?

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have the following code.

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T>
constexpr bool is_vector() {
    return is_same<C<T>, vector<T>>::value;
}

template <typename Value, enable_if_t<is_vector<???>()>>
void my_function(Value &value) {
}
```

**How do I invoke `is_vector` in order to check if `Value` is an instance of the std::vector class template?**

Comment: You keep using this "parametrized" terminology. Don't. Use terminology that other people use, too, so that you can be understood. Consider "class template" vs "class". Or, in this case, "an instance of the `std::vector` class template".

Comment: Why can't you apply [the answer given to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29055925/560648)? `return is_same_template<C, std::vector>::value`, no?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want to know if something is a vector at compile time?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I could. But, I didn't want to make this question too complicated...

Comment: @NeilKirk, I'm trying to determine whether something is a sequence container at compile time. `vector` happens to be one of them. I wouldn't need any of these, if we had concept in the standard today...

Comment: Can you query the tags on the iterators?

Comment: @BeyondSora: This question wouldn't need to _exist_ if you simply took the solution you've already been given.

Comment: _"I'm trying to determine whether something is a sequence container at compile time"_ Strange requirement. Usually you rely on iterator behaviours instead (e.g. RandomIterator)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't remember having ever heard of an *instance* of a class template. I'd probably confuse it with *instances of classes*. Why not a *specialization of the `std::vector` class template*?

Comment: @dyp The standardese is *specialization*, FWIW.

Comment: @dyp: An instance of a class template is a class. Instantiation, while somewhat garbled English, is admittedly probably the more common term here. I don't like using "specialization", especially with those who have not yet quite grasped what templates _are_: the symmetry of "instance" (or "instantiation") is far more compelling.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe it was just the unfortunate position of the line wrap in the OP :) (The line is wrapped between "class" and "template" in my browser.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is writing another trait...

```
template<class C>
struct is_vector : std::false_type {};

template<class T, class A>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T,A>>: std::true_type {};
```

Comment: I finally understand what LightnessRacesinOrbit means by if I just use your previous solution, I wouldn't have this problem at all. Thank you guys so much! I have so much to learn...